# Do I need to add navigation bar item in all screen if I use UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7

I am using UITabBarController and it has 4 view controllers. And every ViewControllers is embedded with UINavigationController.

Now I want to have a navigation left item which will be menu and everything in this side menu is common for all four screen. I have different classes for all four ViewControllers. Do I need to add same code in all class? or anything I can do to reduce code?

Comment: create one NSObject Class, protocol  and call where u need

Comment: Just add this navigation left item in your subclass UINavigationController

Comment: I really don't have any idea to work on subclass of like UINavigationController and UITabbarController. Can you be specific?

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this one..

https://cocoapods.org/pods/RESideMenu

this is the best librery for side menu ...and yes you need to add same code in all class...

only add code of Sidemenu in all tab bar class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I just take a UIView and animate it by changing its frame on button action. Then I will add UITableView in this side view. I want it simple. I just stay away from library which in my case is hard to understand. Maybe I didn't give a try

Comment: And I also need UIImageView at top in side menu.

Comment: yes , everything is possible..you have to try from Github..and understand example for what you want..just try this sidemenu in github...   and you also add UIimageview at the top..but you have to change library..

Comment: Use MFsidemenu for Add UIimageview in top in side menu...https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu...just change the Height in sidemenu UItableview